# How to Extract some specific dictionaries from list of dictionaries column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas dataframe where one column contains list of dictionaries.

```
names             
 [{'Open-pending':123}, {'Past-Pending':456}, {'Open-Closed':789},{'Past-Closed': 453}]
```

How to extract dictionaries only when the key starts with Past.
Desired output:

```
new_names
[{'Past-Pending':456}, {'Past-Closed': 453}]
```

Comment: Can you have multiple keys in each dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dictionaries with single keys, use a list comprehension with a test on the key:

```
df['names'] = [[d for d in l if next(iter(d), '').startswith('Past')]
               for l in df['names']]
```

Output:

```
                                           names
0  [{'Past-Pending': 456}, {'Past-Closed': 453}]
```